# Excel Sum Based on Selection of Item List

Tags: excel, list, formula

**My excel sheet lists County's and its tax rate. 
At the end of the month, I have to document the sales tax of each sale. 
I have 3 columns that looks something like this: 
Column A is Select a County (This is created in the form of a drop-down list) 
Column B is the selection from column A's rate
Column C is Sale Contract Number
Column D is the amount of sales tax column C was

How can I create a sum for a given county (Column A) using the monetary values in Column D?

I already tried //=SUMIFS(A:A, D:D, "=Albany")//
 but that didn't do the trick

I want to calculate the total sales tax for every county once I completed the list. County's are selected via a drop-down list, and sales tax (column D) are manually entered. 
Any suggestions?**

Comment: For `SUMIFS`, the first argument is the `Sum_range`, and the second argument is `criteria_range1`.  If you are summing column D, based on column A being equal to Albany, you need to reverse those range arguments.

Comment: You should also look at creating a Pivot Table